# Testing action dispatch in redux-form submission handler

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-form

I'm writing a Jest test to check if an action is dispatched when I submit a form built with redux-form. I'm stubbing the action and invoking the submission handler `handleFormSubmit` directly. I'm expecting `dispatch` to be called with my stubbed action as the parameter but the assertion keeps failing. The application does work as expected but I can't figure out why this test is failing.

Here is the component (a simple login form):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { userSignIn } from "../actions";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import * as formValidators from '../utils/formValidators';
import TextInput from '../components/TextInput';
import Button from '../components/Button';

/* 

... styled components code

*/

export class Login extends React.Component {
    handleFormSubmit = (credentials) => {
        this.props.userSignIn(credentials);
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <StyledDiv>   
                <StyledForm onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit)}>
                    <fieldset className="form-group">
                        <Field name="email" component={TextInput} type="text" label="Email"/>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset className="form-group">
                        <Field name="password" component={TextInput} type="password" label="Password"/>
                    </fieldset>

                    <Button type="submit" label="Sign In"/>
                </StyledForm>
            </StyledDiv>
        );
    }
}

const LoginContainer = reduxForm({
    form: 'login',
    validate: formValidators.createValidator({
        email:formValidators.email,
        password:formValidators.required
    })
})(Login);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        authenticationError: state.auth.error
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        userSignIn: (credentials) => dispatch(userSignIn(credentials))
    }
}

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) =>
    Object.assign({}, stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(LoginContainer);
```

Here is my Jest test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ConnectedLogin, {Login} from '../../containers/Login';
import EnzymeToJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import * as Actions from '../../actions';

describe('Connected Login component', () => {
    const mockStore = configureMockStore();
    let wrapper;
    let store;

    beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore();
        wrapper = shallow(<ConnectedLogin store={store} />);
    });

    test('userSignIn is dispatched', () => {
        const storeSpy = sinon.spy(store, 'dispatch');
        const credentials = {
            email: "foo@bar.com",
            password: "foobar"
        };

        const stub = sinon.stub(Actions, 'userSignIn').callsFake(() => {
            return {
                type: 'USER_SIGN_IN',
            }
        });

        //need to dive multiple times since this is a component in a redux form in a redux container
        wrapper.dive().dive().dive().dive().instance().handleFormSubmit(credentials);
        expect(storeSpy.calledWith(stub())).toBe(true)
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this is working? `this.props.handleSubmit` is undefined.

Comment: @moritz-schmitz-v-hülst Yes I believe that is passed as props from the redux-form wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `this.props.handleSubmit` in

> function mapDispatchToProps

The dispatch method invoked form the above function and corresponding call will get in your action file

Comment: handleSubmit is provided by the ReduxForm decorator

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was declaring my spy after after mounting the component. Declaring the spy BEFORE mounting the component fixed the issue.